# Finishing a sentence with "writing about..."

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Is the following question grammatically and semantically correct? I'm not sure about adding words after *about*.

> *What are some newspapers writing about the Arsenal manager?*

They are spreading gossip about the Arsenal manager's possible decision to leave the club.

Comment: about the Arsenal manager is a prepositional phrase. "What are you writing about?"

Comment: Yes, I know you're writing about the Arsenal manager, but *what* are you writing about him?  (The obvious analogy is “what are you talking about”, but *talk* is transitive and *write* is transitive even if its object is unmentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is OK. "about" modifies "writing".

Compare with:

> The newspapers write **about** the manager that...

Do not confuse your example with:

> What are the newspapers writing **about**?

In the case of the last example, we do not know the information written in the newspapers.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. "About the ..." is a prepositional phrase that modifies what.  If we reorder the sentence this becomes clear:

> What **about the Arsenal manager** are some newspapers writing?

In general, it's a good idea to keep modifying phrases close to the word they modify, but this is just good *style* and not an actual *rule*. Sometimes a different order just *sounds* better.

Comment: Hmmm...  *What about are you  talking?*  *What about him are you saying?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  I think in your first example *talk about* is a phrasal verb.  The second seems fine, although not perhaps the most natural way to say it.